# Does the new Serious Sam 3 DLC include new coop content?

Tags: serious-sam-3-bfe

Serious Sam 3: Jewel of the Nile appears to include three new campaign missions. Are those playable in coop too? The description in Steam doesn't really mention it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The three new campaign missions in the DLC are indeed playable in coop (albeit players might desire more content after that).

Answer (score 1):

Hello Serious Sam 3: Jewels of the Nile contains with the main game 12 campaign missions including **co-op for 2 to 4 players** in the campaign or survival, as well as **available** in the **DLC**, which also includes even more co-op modes like Coin Co-op and Classic Co-op.